# Excel spreadsheet with apostrophes causing problems

Tags: microsoft-excel

I received an excel spreadsheet with credit card numbers (CC number), dates, text etc. All of the numbers have an apostrophe ' in front of them. When I remove the apostrophe from the cc number it makes the last number a 0, when I remove it from dollar amounts it makes '40.00 into 0000000000000040. I would like to remove the apostrophe so I can search the excel sheet. I am not sure what to do. I have tried formatting cell, going into file--options--lotus compatibility and nothing has worked.

Comment: sounds like a custom number format problem.

Comment: You can do a custom number format of 0000000000000000 (that's 16 zeros).

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work either. Even if I find the ' and replace with nothing it messes up the fields

Comment: The apostrophe is probably so the numbers get treated like text (you don't do math on a credit card number and you don't want to get into floating point rounding errors or implied decimal places).  For things like dollar amounts, you could use functions to convert them to numerical or currency values.  You could also use string functions to delete the apostrophe and leave the  credit card number as text.  Rather than trying to modify the values in place, just put the translated values in new cells.

Comment: sort of surprised no one mentioned it is a bad idea to store cc#s this way for pci compliance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- In any blank cell, type 1
- Select the cell where you typed 1, and press Control + C
- Select the cell/range which you want to convert to numbers
- Select Paste –> Paste Special (Key Board Shortcut – Alt + E + S)
- In the Paste Special Dialogue box, select Multiply (in operations category)

This would remove the apostrophe and convert the text back to a number.

Comment: For credit card numbers, you don't want them converted to a number.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using the [=TEXT()](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?CTT=5&origin=HA010277524&CorrelationId=311cdfb0-643d-45f5-9561-528d5f34bbb5&ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ) function to put in the format you wish, but I found it's easier to just use [=RIGHT()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f) since it's already text -

```
=RIGHT(A1,16)
```

This will strip the `'` from the numbers, assuming they are all 16 digit numbers. Then just hide the original column.